A problem with the definition of ergodicity in "Evaluating gambles using dynamics, O.Peters"
In the paper we are presented with a additive time stochastic process:
$$ W_{t+ \delta t \times T} - W_t = \sum^T_{i=1} D_i   $$
Where $W_t$ represents the wealth at time $t$ , $\delta t$ is the length of a time increment  ,and $D_i$ are iid discrete random variables (corresponding to gambles).
The author then states that this process is stationary (trivially ergodic) and because of that we should have :
$$ \underset{T \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{\delta t~ T} ( W_{t+ \delta t T} - W_t) = \frac{1}{\delta t}\mathbb{E}[D_1]$$
Which is supposed to be the equality of time averages and ensemble averages in an ergodic system.
My question is:
Isn't the LHS supposed to be
$$\underset{T \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{\delta t~ T}  \sum^T_{i=1} ( W_{t+\delta t \times i} - W_t)$$
that is we must sum at each time step then average. Am I missing something here ?

The sum is hidden in the expression $W_{t + \delta t T} - W_t$:
$$W_{t + T\delta t} - W_t = (W_{t + \delta t} - W_t) + (W_{t+2\delta t} - W_{t +\delta t}) + (W_{t+3\delta t} - W_{t +2\delta t}) + \dots + (W_{t+T\delta t} - W_{t +(T-1)\delta t}) $$
So you can see the limit really is of the sample means of the per-increment differences as $T \to \infty$.
